# How to validate multiple form fields in MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, field

I was trying to build a login form, where the user has to add this data in a form: first name, last name, studentnumber and email.

I have a test user in my MySQL database, but so far it's not working. Here's my code:

```
<?php
//Start session//
session_start();

//Include database connection file and header file//
include_once('resources/includes/database.inc.php');
include_once('header.php');

?>

<!-- Login form -->

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
//Escape de gebruikersnaam
$sFirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$sLastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$sStudentNumber = ($_POST['studentnumber']);
$sEmail = ($_POST['email']);
$sSQL = 'SELECT `id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `studentNumber`, `email`, `accepted` FROM   `student` WHERE `firstName` = \'' . $sFirstName . '\'';
$rsSQL = mysql_query($sSQL);
$aUser = mysql_fetch_array($rsSQL);
  //Er is geen rij gevonden en $aUser is false:
//Dat betekent dat er geen user is met de opgegeven gebruikersnaam
if($aUser == false)
{
    echo '<strong>Deze gebruiker is niet gevonden</strong>';
}
//Vergelijk de rest
elseif($aUser['lastname'] != $sLastName)
{
  echo '<strong>De achternaam is niet bekend</strong>';
}

elseif($aUser['studentnumber'] != $sStudentNumber)
{
    echo '<strong>Het studentnummer is niet geldig</strong>';
}

elseif($aUser['email'] != $sEmail)
{
  echo '<strong>Het e-mailadres is niet bekend</strong>';
}

//Inloggen gelukt
else
{        //De combinatie is goed, maak de sessie aan
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $aUser['id'];

    //Verstuur de gebruiker door
    header("location: studentloggedin.php");

    //Mocht de redirect hierboven niet werken:
    echo '<strong>Je bent ingelogd, klik <a href="studentloggedin.php">hier</a> om door te gaan.</strong>';
}
}
?>

<form method="post">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Voornaam</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Achternaam</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="lastname" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Studentnummer</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="studentnumber" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Email</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Inloggen" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('resources/templates/homecontent.template.html');
print $html;
include_once('resources/templates/footer.template.html');
?>
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? If I fill everything in correctly according to my database user, I get: 'De achternaam is niet bekend' (Last name isn't recognized). Perhaps I should check the validation in the MySQL query?

Comment: Hey @JakeGould, I'm sorry you feel that way. You think only people who do this professionally should get help? I guess I'm not asking any more questions here on stackoverflow then. I'm very interested in this subject and maybe want to do this professionally later, I'm only 20 now and just started to learn.

Comment: To answer this question requires going through a lot of code. This makes it hard to give good answers without spending dispropotionate amounts of time on the question; most people will rather move on to another question. If you distill the question down to the smallest possible sample that reproduces the problem the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well. The edited question does not have to do the same thing as the whole of the code, it only needs to reproduce the one aspect that you need help with.

Comment: @user3671823 The purpose of this site is to house questions and answers that are generally useful to future readers IN ADDITION to your immediate problem. When you dump a huge wad of code on the site full of multiple problems, your question becomes "this code does not work. Why?", which as you can imagine is not useful to anyone in the world except the person with this specific code -- you. I am self-taught, and I can tell you straight away one of the most valuable skills you can learn is how to distill problems and debug code. Isolate the specific problem and ask about that, and only that.

Answer (score 1):

Array keys are case sensitive.

`$aUser['lastname']` != `$aUser['lastName']`

You also should move away from `mysql_` as the MySQL API is deprecated.  Use PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements to avoid SQL injections.  Right now, your query is open to injections using a `$_POST` variable directly in the query.

For debugging purposes, I suggest you print out the array if you're having trouble in the future using: `print_r($aUser)`.  It may have saved you a trip here.